# Getting data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => purple.txt
        [1] => pinky.txt
        [2] => original stuff.txt
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => purp1.txt
        [1] => pink1.txt
        [2] => original stuff1.txt
        [3] => increment1.txt
    )

)
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6395.tmp
        [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A6.tmp
        [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A7.tmp
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A8.tmp
        [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A9.tmp
        [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63AA.tmp
        [3] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63AB.tmp
    )
```

I would like to match the array keys with the proper array keys from the second array for example I would like to be able get the file name

each

```
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
```

is a new row and I would like to eventually save all the file names from that row in mysql so i can call the links....

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => purple.txt
```

and match it with

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6395.tmp
```

so I can use them together for file storage and so on......

The following php is

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])=== true){
$files = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$files_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($files);
echo '<pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($files_tmp);
echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: I have tried multiple array merge functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would iterate over multiple uploaded files. Assuming you have these input element names:

```
file[0][0]
file[0][1]
file[1][0]
...

foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $row => $rowfiles) {
    foreach ($rowfiles as $index => $name) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$row][$index];

        // do stuff with $name and $tmp_name
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gvice I've updated my answer, I'm assuming you meant to say that you're using multi-dimensional file input elements.

Comment: [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => purple.txt
        [1] => pinky.txt
        [2] => original stuff.txt
    )      and....
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php6395.tmp
        [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A6.tmp
        [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php63A7.tmp
    ) belong to one row I would like to maintain which row they are in so I can store them according to the row and store the file links in mysql according to the row, unless there is a way to pass a value to the file which can notify which row it belongs to (multiple rows of multiple file upload inputs)

Comment: awesome thank you so much print_r($row.$index); all day affair sad to say. do you by any chance know how i would be able to insert the file names from each row into an array to store into mysql..... dont worry either way.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$rows = array();

foreach( $first_array as $key => $value )
{
    foreach( $value as $k => $v )
    {
        $rows[] = array( 'filename' => $v, 'path' => $second_array[$key][$k] );
    }
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $rows, true ) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: this is very close but it combines each upload with the file path Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => pinky.txt
            [path] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4D5B.tmp
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => original stuff.txt
            [path] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4D5C.tmp
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [filename] => increment.txt
            [path] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4D5D.tmp
        )
)